# In an isolated SMPS feedback design, how could optocoupler latency be higher than the switching period?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, opto-isolator, isolation, feedback, latency

I often see this in practical SMPS designs. An optocoupler & voltage reference pair is used for informing the controller section about the output voltage level. However, when I read the datasheet of the optocoupler in the circuit, I see that the given signal characteristics "rise time" and "fall time" are higher than the switching period of the controller circuit.

#### Example

See [this circuit](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/PoeExampleTiTPS23753RedLine.png) in [this article](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/galvanic-isolation-Purpose-and-Methodologies/).

[image: Example Circuit Design]

In the schematics, it says that the switching frequency of this circuit is `250kHz`, which means the switching period is `4us`. In the [optocoupler datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FOD817A-194238.pdf), the rise time is given as `4us` (typical) and `18us` (maximum). The fall time is `3us` (typical) and `18us` (maximum). The signal has to rise and then fall, so it takes typically `7us` (`36us` at maximum) for a pulse. An engineer must make his design considering the worst case circumstances, so we should take the maximum pulse time as `36us`, which is `9` times the switching period.

Wouldn't it mean that the controller will respond to an output change 9 periods late? Is this much latency acceptable, doesn't it cause output voltage level controlling problems? Or, is there anything I'm missing here? Can you please explain me how does this kind of SMPS designs work with all these slow optocouplers?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the opto-coupler is powered by the DC after all the filtering components, so the feedback delay will be much slower.  The operation of the supply will have a parameter of "Load Response", "Load Regulation" (or something similar) that lists the typical response to a sudden load change, (time wise this is likely in the range of several mS).  The extra (or missing) switching pulses generated during this response time will be well filtered by time they reach the DC output.  So the "latency" in uS is not very critical in this case.

Comment: So the optocoupler is operating in analogue mode, coupling the DC output level back to the control?

Comment: @pjc50, correct - and the extra circuitry on the LED's cathode side helps to control this too.

Answer (score 4):

The opto-coupler is not responding to the switching frequency of the fly back converter so therefore, the rise time and fall time specifications are irrelevant. Although the opto-coupler is generally thought of as a digital device, for this type of circuit it is operating linearly; neither being in saturation nor fully turned off. This means it does operate fluently at good speed.

Admittedly the linear region is small but the action of negative feedback keeps it sat in that linear region.

Comment: I want to study this kind feedback loop solely for SMPS design. How do search it in Google? Is there an online article?

Comment: I would consider using LTSpice - linear tech have a vast number of switchers that are simulateable. I think this is your best route.

Comment: @hkBattousai, This kind of feedback loop is quite common in isolated power supplies (chargers, ATX etc.,).  [This] (https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND381-D.PDF) link provides a good intro to this subject